# When cloning a PDB over dblink in Oracle 19c, is it possible to use file_name_convert without specifying entire paths?

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c, multi-tenant

## Context

*Oracle version: 19.13*
On server 1 I have a production database, with a CDB named (for the purpose of this question) `CDBPROD` and a PDB named `PDBPROD`.
The datafiles are distributed in multiple directories :

```
  /opt/data/CDBPROD/something/CDBPROD/PDBPROD/
  /opt/data/CDBPROD/something_else/CDBPROD/PDBPROD/
  /opt/data/CDBPROD/and_another_one/CDBPROD/PDBPROD/
```

I want to clone `PDBPROD` to another server (server 2), where a CDB named `CDBTEST` already exists. I want the cloned PDB to be named `PDBTEST` and its datafiles in these directories:

```
  /opt/data/CDBTEST/something/CDBTEST/PDBTEST/
  /opt/data/CDBTEST/something_else/CDBTEST/PDBTEST/
  /opt/data/CDBTEST/and_another_one/CDBTEST/PDBTEST/
```

## What I did

Following the Oracle docs [Cloning a PDB or Non-CDB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/multi/cloning-a-pdb.html) and [CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-PLUGGABLE-DATABASE.html), I created in `PDBPROD` a user for the dblink, granted him `connect, create session` (to use as dblink) and `create pluggable database` (to clone the pdb), created the dblink in `CDBTEST` and issued the following command in `sqlplus` (logged in as sysdba on  ̀CDBTEST`):

```
create pluggable database PDBTEST from PDBPROD@MY_DBLINK_TO_PDBPROD
       file_name_convert= ('CDBPROD','CDBTEST','PDBPROD','PDBTEST')
       service_name_convert=('PDBPROD','PDBTEST');
```

No error during the creation, and afterwards I could open the PDB without any problem.
However, the datafiles of `PDBTEST` are located in the following paths:

```
  /opt/data/CDBPROD/something/CDBPROD/PDBTEST/
  /opt/data/CDBPROD/something_else/CDBPROD/PDBTEST/
  /opt/data/CDBPROD/and_another_one/CDBPROD/PDBTEST/
```

## Question

I could not find in the documentation any mention of the file name conversion stopping after one replacement is done. Is it actually how it works (in that case I have no choice but to put the full paths), or did I do something wrong ?

I am aware that I can put the full paths and it probably will work, but I am a little lazy (and there are a lot more than 3 paths in reality) and most of all I like to understand why things don't work as I expect them to.